# Get objects from Parse and put them in an array in Java?

Tags: java, parse-platform

I have a `ParseObject` class with a "Score" column filled with int values. Those values (using a `ParseQuery`) must go inside an array. The problem is that I can't figure out how to do it and the docs in the website seem to give examples and lessons only on retrieving object with known ID (which is useless to me).

This is my code:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Margherita"); // Object      is classname
    query.setLimit(1000);
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
    query.whereExists("PunteggioMargherita");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, com.parse.ParseException e) {
            int votiTemp;
            String[] arryprova = new String[10];
            if (e == null) {
                for(int i = 0; i < arryprova.length; i++) {
                    arryprova[i] = list.toString();

                }
                votiTemp = arryprova

                prova.setText(votiMargherita);

                Log.d("PunteggioMargherita", "Retrieved " + list.size() + " scores");
            } else {
                Log.d("PunteggioMargherita", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }

        }


    });
```

Comment: Let's start with this:  what are you having difficulties with?

Comment: `The problem is that I can't figure out how to do it` How to do what, exactly?  Building a Parse query?  Constructing an array?  Populating the array?

Comment: I have difficulties with taking the values from Parse.com from the column "PunteggioMargherita" and insert them in an array